# Using SD card from Android 7 in Android 6

Tags: sd-card

I got a new 'phone, with Android 7. I don't like it and plan to continue to use my Android 6 phone.

When I put the SD card into the Android 7, I vaguely remember something about it formatting - and encrypting? - it, and saying that the data would only be accessible on that 'phone.

When I put it in the Android 6 'phone, Settings/Storage and USB says that there is no SD card inserted.

It also offers me the option to "forget" the card and says that if I do so, all data on the card will be lost forever.

Two important points:

1. I don't care about the data & don't mind losing it; but I don't want the o/s to believe that there is no SD card slot.
2. the SD card & SIM slide in together on a little tray and that tray is stuck. So, it is quite probable that the SD card is not physically recognized.

Before I use brute force (and a thin knife) to get the tray out, is there any way to tell the 'phone "hey, you might have an SD card which is encrypted, and I am quite happy with reformatting it, just so long as you recognize it"?

Comment: Afraid not. If the device recognises it it will ask for formatting. If it is not mounted, there is nothing you can do except use your knife skills

Comment: Second thoughts - if they're is an option in your device (Incidentally do mention device in question) to decrypt try that. I had similar issues. MM SD card not recognised in N and vice versa. Simply copied data to PC, formatted card in phone and copied back

Comment: I can't see how to format the SD card in the new 'phone, as it is not recognized :-(  Time for some knifery, methinks

Comment: I was only illustrating that MM and N behave differently with SD cards. But do see if decrypt his

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to connect your old phone to your computer and copy the data from the SD card to  the computer. Then choose forget on your old phone, try to get the SD card out and put it in the new phone. It will prompt to format the SD card. If it doesn't, go to Settings > Storage and tap on the SD card. It will ask to format it. If that still doesn't work, put your SD card into the computer and format it from there, preferably FAT32.